# No viable conversion from int for custom class

Tags: c++

I have written a UTF8 character class, with the following methods:

```
typedef uint32_t CodePoint; // This is meant to represent any unicode character

explicit Char(const char c);
explicit Char(const CodePoint cp);

Char& operator=(const char c);
Char& operator=(const CodePoint cp);
```

But when I try to construct one of my new class by passing it a number I get an error:

```
utf8::Char c = 0x20AC; // No viable conversion from int to utf8::Char
utf8::Char c(0x20AC);  // Call to constructor of 'utf8::Char' is ambiguous
```

Why am I seeing these errors?

Comment: `explicit` prevents copy-intialization. The second one is because `int` can convert to `char` just as easily as `uint32_t`.

Comment: @chris That has fixed the errors, thanks! Is there a way to say "Use the `CodePoint` constructor for everything apart from `char`". It's advantageous to have the `char` initializers as it means no encoding needs to be performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `typedef uint32_t CodePoint; // This is meant to represent any unicode character`

Do you realise C++11 defines a distinct `char32_t` type for that purpose?

> `utf8::Char c = 0x20AC; // No viable conversion from int to utf8::Char`

This is not an assignment, it's a construction. This syntax is called copy initialization and is equivalent to:

```
utf8::Char c = utf8::Char(0x20AC);
```

except that the conversion from `int` to `utf8::Char` is implicit, and therefore cannot use an `explicit` constructor.

> `utf8::Char c(0x20AC);  // Call to constructor of 'utf8::Char' is ambiguous`

A conversion from `int` to `char` is no better or worse than a conversion from `int` to `uint32_t`.

> Is there a way to say "Use the `CodePoint` constructor for everything apart from `char`".

Yes, the usual way to say "everything" in the C++ type system is a template:

```
explicit Char(char c);
template<typename T>
  explicit Char(T cp);
```

The `Char(char)` constructor will be preferred when the argument is `char` (because overload resolution prefers non-templates are preferred to templates if they would otherwise be ambiguous), and for everything else the constructor template will be used.

Because you don't want the template constructor to accept *every* type, you might want to make it an error if it's called with non-integral types. In C++11 you can do that like this:

```
template<typename T>
  explicit Char(T cp)
  {
    static_assert(std::is_integral<T>::value, "utf8::Char should only be constructed from integral types");
  }
```

Comment: Ahh, it all makes sense now, sorry for my ignorance, I didn't know about `char32_t` or about the copy initialization.

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out that anytime you overload on any integral type (including `char`), you should provide an overload for `int`, precisely because that is the (default) type of integral literals.  And the template constructor probably isn't a good idea, since it will accept _any_ type, and you don't really want it converting `double` or whatever.

Comment: @JamesKanze, yes, I was going to suggest constraining the template but decided it was probably more information than the OP needed. I'll edit the answer now though. N.B. the `char` constructor will accept `double` arguments, even without the template there.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I know.  I'm not sure how to best handle this situation.  (As I said, I'd just overload for `int`, to catch integral constants, and hope the user wasn't completely stupid.)

Answer (score -3):

0x20AC is digit, so you must provide another overload constructor.